# Rails complaining attribute doesn't exist, but it works for other people

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I should note before any of this, that my friend pulled from my git repo and it works perfectly for him.

The database has the attribute, and the `attr_accessible` is set. But Rails is throwing this error `undefined method 'is_free' for #<Account:0x007fb53bc91ec0>` when trying to access it in view.

Database for ref: `t.boolean  "is_free", :default => false`

The other really bizarre thing is you can see the attribute exists in console.

```
1.9.3p194 :005 > a.is_free
 => false
```

I have dropped, created and re-migrated the database without success. I have deleted the entire folder, re-cloned from git and re-created database without success.

I have no idea what is going on.. it's just acting haywire. Please help, I'm losing my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods like that only exist if the way you requested it fetched that column. By default that's how it works, but it is possible to restrict which columns are loaded with `select`.

A really simple way to find out what data you have is to put this in your view:

```
raise a.attributes.inspect
```

Where `a` is the record with the problem. You should see an `is_free` attribute if it was loaded. If not, look in `log/development.log` to see what `SELECT` query is executed.

Comment: Thanks, that's a handy way of inspecting. `is_free` is not there. I have something to add: I thought it might be something with the database in Rails, and this only makes it seem more likely. I run the postgres.app for the database. In other application's, when I quit the app and run `foreman start` it says `unable to connect to localhost`, as it should. However, in this app it starts successfully. I have the `gem pg` and `database.yml` setup the same for both, and I double checked `brew list` to make sure I didn't have another postgres installation, but I don't. I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: Oh and to answer your question, the SELECT loads the entire object: `SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]` so it should be there.

Comment: I'll award you the answer, I figured it out thanks to you: turns out the Heroku env variables were pulled into the .env file and so the database it was referencing was the http one not locally!

Comment: Ah, yes, that can happen from time to time. It's like testing on staging and wondering by the bug's still showing up, mistaking that site for the one on your local development machine.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
a.update_attribute(:is_free, :true)
```

To

```
a.update_attribute(:is_free, true)
```

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies that the console is working correctly. But I cannot understand why the Rails view still claims it does not exist. Both Active Admin and the regular view throw the `undefined method` error despite it being in `attr_accessible`.